# Does we have Json rest api for GetUserAvailability operation in outlook exchange server api?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-restapi

I have implement Soap api for getting the free/busy data for particular person . But

Is there is any rest api for this . Because rest api is more flexible for implementation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa564001(v=exchg.150).aspx

**Here is how i implement Soap request.**

[How can i get the outlook free / busy rest api for my own company email exchange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250009/how-can-i-get-the-outlook-free-busy-rest-api-for-my-own-company-email-exchange/49252950#49252950)

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have it in MS Graph. It's called Find Meeting Times API.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_findmeetingtimes

Comment: How can be use this url format for exchange server . Exchanges server url is like this --- https://--your-exchange-url--/EWS/Exchange.asmx . How can i get this ?  Is i am missing something .  This api look like for online account .

Comment: The URL you are referring to is called EWS protocol. Exchange 2016 has Rest API support as well. So if you have Exchange server 2016 you can use Rest api there as well : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#FindMeetingTimes